# Typo3 - Fluid - Content Header output

Tags: php, typo3, tx-news

I have an issue with Typo3 Extension tx_News.

I should Display the tt_content Header in the General fluid template.
I tried to found any Solutions by search in Google, unfortunately I don't found any solution.

I tried to get the Output by:
- {contentObject.header}
- {contentObj.header}
- {tt_content.header}
- {data-header}

Unfortunately I don't found the correct solution and would appreciate if anybody can help me

Comment: Could you add your TYPO3 version (and, if it is related to tx_news, also that)?
If you are talking about the header that is set in every tt_content element and you are using fluid_styled_content, this layout https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Layouts/Default.html is used which includes Partials/Header/All.html and finally https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Partials/Header/Header.html

Comment: Ups, sorry that I forgot to mention the Version, is Typo3 Version 9 and tx_news Version 7.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The news extension adds the content object data in the variable `contentObjectData`, so you can use `{contentObjectData.header}` to get the tt_content header value in your news templates.

Comment: Thanks for your Input, this I didn't tried :-(
It runs perfect.

Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: Lucky_luck, please mark this answer as the best answer, which increases the reputations of Rudy Gnodde, and he will continue to support you and other users. This is how Stackoverflow works :)

Comment: May Rudy you can help me on another issue, I tried to use the Header_link but I don't get the link in frontend. I tried with:
<f:link.typolink parameter="{contentObjectData.header_link}"> but this doesn't works :-(

Comment: The Header_link is planned to use in the list item to link from a created shortlist to complete list. Therefore I want to use the Header_link due I don't found any other solution.